# VBA, Finding LastCol With LastRow + Select

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that currently finds the last row on a worksheet, pairs that with a defined last column and starting cell, and then selects all of it for printing.

```
Set Sheet = Worksheets("Summary PNL (bpnl by bucket)")
Set StartCell = Range("A9")
LastRow = Sheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Sheet.Range("A9:I" & LastRow).Select
```

I am now dealing with a dynamic column in addition to a dynamic row. In theory this isn't a difficult add however row 9 only has data in column A (Range A9), B through I (example ending column) are blank on that row. Any insight?

Comment: you can click `A9` and press Ctrl+A. If that selects the range you want, then you can use `Range("A9").CurrentRegion.Select` in VBA

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you want to print all the cells that are not empty nor unformated, you can use:

```
Worksheets("Summary PNL (bpnl by bucket)").UsedRange.Select
```

That will select all the range that is used.

Anyway, to find the last cell, you can use this property with the specialcells method like this:

```
LastRow = Worksheets("Summary PNL (bpnl by bucket)").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than look for the last row look for the last cell.  Then all you have to do is select everything between the first cell and last cell.

This will fail if there's nothing on your sheet as it will try to reference row 0 and column 0 (`Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed`).

I'd suggest using a function to find the last cell first - one that will return a range object even if the sheet is empty.  There's plenty of examples on here.

```
Sub test()

    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim LastCell As Range

    Set Sheet = Worksheets("Summary PNL (bpnl by bucket)")
    Set StartCell = Range("A9")
    Set LastCell = Sheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    Sheet.Range(StartCell, LastCell).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good point, didn't think of it that way. Here's a twist though, what if there is irrelevant content in other sections of the sheet. Whether it be blank formulas for example, or an empty pivot. This method is perfect assuming the sheet is "vanilla" of sorts.

Comment: I suppose I could use a series of xlLeft xlUp but that's obviously not ideal